# JSF 1.2: Too many small session beans: Is it bad and what the alternatives

Tags: performance, session, jsf, javabeans

There's a JSF 1.2 application with no way to switch to another version/technology in the observable future. It's often needed to show a small (modal) form that needs some state kept across several requests. After the work is done (confirmed or canceled) this state is not needed until the form opens again. There are a lot of such forms and session objects (separate per-form session beans or members of special huge session beans) are used for keeping their state. The sessions may last long enough, probably the whole working day. So a lot of objects unnecessarily load the session scope.

Is there a simple, standard way of cleaning a session object when it's no longer needed? What are your solutions regarding to that?

Comment: What we are doing now. Similar to anil's suggestion we have a session beans that contain fields and access methods for these small form-specific objects (accessed in JSP like `#{containerBean.formBean}`). But this approach needs special manual programming for concurrency issues. Also my IDE (Eclipse) is often hanging with code navigation on this container bean (as the number of members is very huge already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ Alex,

As you have mentioned that you have multiple view/page that you want to render/preserve  in multiple requests and that remain persist until user session is not expire .
This is only because bean scope is session , May be you have did it is to avoid multiple db call to achieve performance just avoid reloading same info from database on each request.

I think you create a collection in user session bean or any other session bean where you find best (as per your choice but I will advise to create New Bean for only this purpose).
In this collection you just put your model data what you want to display on page  do not register this bean in context file. persist the object where you required like you have three pages .P1,P2 & P3 and after P3 you want to remove model1 (your pojo)from session then on navigation event just remove model1 from collection .

```
//Sample code which  help to understand what I am saying 


@Session
UserBean {
  Map tempBean<Obejct,String>=new HashMap<Object,String>();

        //just for example  suppose you want to load Model1

        public Model1  viewP1() {
            if(tempBean.get("P1info")==null){//key for P1 view 
            Model1 m1=db.getP1info();
            tempBean.put("P1info",m1);
        }

        return (m1)tempBean.get("P1info");
    }
}
```

To remove the Model1 data from session just set the  value as null for key "P1info" in case of above code, You can use  WeakHashMap,If you do not want to remove key from Map.But make sure to delete value part on your trigger of event after which you do not want to persist the Model1 value in session.

I hope this will work in your case .Please let me know in case of any problem in implementation since I have not  shared working code  ,but only showing concept.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give a look here
[link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13224_01/wlw/docs103/guide/ejb/session/conSessionBeanLifeCycle.html) 
I would run a remove on all the object once "*the work is done*".